# I am unable to set the backgroundColor for some reason - M2.3.3

Tags: magento2, php

The issue does not make any sense, The helper is called and defined and I am only adjusting the image properties prior resizing from being initialised as the following:

```
$productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->backgorundColor(array(255,255,255))->resize($image_width, $image_height);
                            $productImageUrl = $productImage->getUrl();
```

And the error log as the following:

```
2020/01/08 21:35:49 [error] 25238#25238: *2028200 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::backgorundColor() in /home/***/m2/public/app/design/frontend/****/***/Smartwave_Filterproducts/templates/grid.phtml:84
Stack trace:
#0 /home/***/m2/public/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
#1 /home/***/m2/public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\FeaturedList\Interceptor), '/home/***/m2/...', Array)
#2 /home/***/m2/public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/***/m2/...')
#3 /home/***/m2/public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1097): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#4 /home/***/m2/public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1101): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework" while reading response header from upstream, client: **********, server: ***.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "***.com", referrer: "https://***.com/****.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just a typo error. I was calling **backgorundColor** when it should be **backgroundColor**

I hope it helps someone else.